# Issue With Session pass in another page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I have created two individual form and store data in one table but problem is that data store individually row ? I want to store data in one row.

and then i created two individual form and store data in one table and my data is store individually row that is issue?

[image]

table name: manager

Database fieldname:

```
- managerid int pk autoincrement
- firstname varchar(50)
- lastname varchar(50)
- address varchar(50)
- permanantaddress varchar(50)
- mno int
- experiance int
- currentcompanyname varchar(50)
- previouscompanyname varchar(50)
- currentsalary int
- expectedsalary    int
```

Registrationform.aspx

```
        <div>
           FirstName: <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
           lastName: <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
```

Registrationform.aspx.cs

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "Insert into manager (firstname,lastname) values(@firstname,@lastname)SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname",txtlname.Text);

            cn.Open();

            int? primaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            this.Session["primaryKey"] = primaryKey;


            if(primaryKey != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Contactus.aspx");
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

        }
```

Contactus.aspx

```
            Address:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtadd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            PermanantAddress:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtperaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Mno:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtmno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Contactus.aspx.cs

```
        string sessionvariable;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           sessionvariable = Session["primaryKey"].ToString();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "update manager set address=@address,permanantaddress=@permanantaddress,mno=@mno where managerid=@managerid";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtadd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permanantaddress", txtperaddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mno", txtmno.Text);

            cn.Open();

            if (sessionvariable != null)
            {  
                **here give an error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@managerid"**

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            cn.Close();

        }
```

**I want to store data in one row.**

**see my watch window Image**:

my problem is that datastore in individually row that is my problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yli5n.png)

Give an Error: here give an error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@managerid"

Comment: I m trying to solve this issue last one day but issue not solved help

Comment: You design is incorrect to begin with. All three forms have only `db` context i.e. `manager` associated with them so it would be very difficult for you to keep a track of what happens when. You should consider creating three separate tables for your three forms and associate the three tables in the `db` based on a foreign key. That architecture is upon you to decide. Currently, what you are trying to achieve is tricky. You could use `Session` to store values from the different Forms and check if the values exists in session from all three forms but that would take some logic.

Comment: @RahulSharma session work in contactus page see above image problem is that data store in individually row?

Comment: Do you want to store a data table in your session variable?

Comment: @Rahul You do realize that on every click of the button, your `this.Session["primaryKey"] = primaryKey;` is incremented by 1 so you will never have the original `id` of the inserted field. You would need to set the `Session` value once only, so on every button click, check if the `Session` exists. If it does, then do nothing, otherwise set it to `primaryKey` field.

Comment: @Atk I want to inserted record(registration form,contactus form,inquire form) store in manager table in one row?

Comment: I understood what your problem is. You have to use update statements and you are using insert statements on every page.

Comment: @Rahul How can you use `update` statement when the primary key is being incremented on every click according to current logic?

Comment: On first page insert the record and get the last inserted I'd using scope identity and then use update on every page.

Comment: @Rahul How can you return the current `managerid ` from your table since on every `db` hit, the `managerid ` will be incremented automatically since `managerid int pk autoincrement` ?

Comment: Scope_identity() function in SQL does that

Comment: @Atk So basically he has to start with an `insert` in either one of the three forms. Then store the `managerid` in a `Sesion` and then do the updates.

Comment: Insert on the registration form and then the updates

Comment: @Rahul I am not quite sure if the flow of your logic is what @Atk is suggesting which is `Registrationform` -> `Contactus`|| `Inquiryform` . If this is the case, then change your logic on `Contactus` and `Inquiryform` to use `update` statement. Also check for the session variable on those forms.

Comment: @RahulSharma ``` managerid int pk autoincrement ? ``` Yes

Comment: @Atk ok as u said but when I remove the scope identity then what?? means how to get the id from database and that id how to store in session? that is the possibility

Comment: @Atk without scope identity when I m work in my project on insert then my problem is how to get the id from database and how to store id in session and pass in another page??

Comment: @Rahul Basically, you need to ensure that your `insert` is only done once during the entire `Session`. Once the `insert` is done, be it from any page, you need to grab the `managerid` and pass it to the `Session`, then on other pages, check for the `Session` and if the `Session` exists, do an updated based on the `managerid` that is in the `Session`. If the `Session` does not exists, do an insert.

Comment: @RahulSharma exactly as u said I  m trying but still face an issue?? I edit my question and the session will work on second page also can u help more plz.

Comment: @RahulSharma I m very near to solve my question and see my uploaded update image help

Comment: add `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerid", sessionvariable);` into your if block

Comment: @NaDeRStar thanks solve the issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string sessionvariable;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sessionvariable = Session["primaryKey"].ToString();
        string query = "update manager set address=@address,permanantaddress=@permanantaddress,mno=@mno where managerid=@managerid";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtadd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permanantaddress", txtperaddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mno", txtmno.Text);

        cn.Open();

        if (sessionvariable != null)
        {  
            **here give an error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@managerid"**

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        cn.Close();

    }
```

[Read More](http://www.csharpmonster.com/)